# How to download a file from command line?

Tags: powershell, wget

I tried wget, powershell and betsadmin, but I can't do it.

Can someone help me ?

The url (which is a live download link if you click on it in a browser) is:

http://ww5.365planetwinall.net/Sport/OddsPrint.ashx?Eventi=7937,7944,7882,7909,7920,7910,7854,18414&ClassiQuota=1,2,51,10&Landscape=1&TipoVis=1&FontSize=6&GroupByEvent=0&printLogo=0&Tema=PlanetWin365

Comment: what's the result you're getting?

Comment: PowerShell: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://ww5.365planetwinall.net/Sport/OddsPrint.ashx?Eventi=7937,7944,7882,7909,7920,7910,7854,18414&ClassiQuota=1,2,51,10&Landscape=1&TipoVis=1&FontSize=6&GroupByEvent=0&printLogo=0&Tema=PlanetWin365' -OutFile 'C:\OddsPrint.pdf'`

Comment: i obtain: access to the path 'c:\Oddsprint.pdf' denied

Comment: Run powershell as `Administrator` or change the `-Outfile` parameter value to a writeable location

Comment: Welcome to Super User. People are security conscious and get concerned when clicking a link immediately downloads an unknown file.  It's a good idea to include a notice on live download links for people who check out the link in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would wonder HOW you tried wget. Just because my result is perfect without any magic:

```
$ wget -O my.pdf "ww5.365planetwinall.net/Sport/OddsPrint.ashx?Eventi=7937,7944,7882,7909,7920,7910,7854,18414&ClassiQuota=1,2,51,10&Landscape=1&TipoVis=1&FontSize=6&GroupByEvent=0&printLogo=0&Tema=PlanetWin365"
--2016-02-28 17:07:20--  http://ww5.365planetwinall.net/Sport/OddsPrint.ashx?Eventi=7937,7944,7882,7909,7920,7910,7854,18414&ClassiQuota=1,2,51,10&Landscape=1&TipoVis=1&FontSize=6&GroupByEvent=0&printLogo=0&Tema=PlanetWin365
Resolving ww5.365planetwinall.net (ww5.365planetwinall.net)... 104.92.107.156
Connecting to ww5.365planetwinall.net (ww5.365planetwinall.net)|104.92.107.156|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 13110 (13K) [application/pdf]
Saving to: 'my.pdf'

100%[=============================================>] 13,110      --.-K/s   in 0.003s

2016-02-28 17:07:21 (3.93 MB/s) - 'my.pdf' saved [13110/13110]
```

I guess you tried similar to some other fellow the other day, who clicked on wget.exe instead of using it at the command line.

Comment: No need to be patronizing. He me simply have forgotten to quote the URL.

Comment: I apologize for helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You can download files through command line:

1) using `iexplore.exe` , example

```
iexplore.exe http://www.example.com/example.exe
```

2) using [Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901)

3) Using youtube-dl [download](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html) to download video form you tube and a few other websites.